# Outlook Interop: Unable to get account information

Tags: c#, outlook, com, office-interop, com-interop

I'm doing the below loop, and the result returns one Account.. however in my Outlook I'am connected to TWO accounts (which i can send emails from)...  My question is, is there any settings i can play with in Outlook to get the below loop to recognize the second account i'am connected to?

```
foreach (Outlook.Account ac in Application.Session.Accounts)
{
    Console.Writeline(ac.UserName);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you have two mailboxes (primary and delegate) in a single Exchange account?

Comment: I Have two exchange accounts

Comment: Image: https://i.ibb.co/6g3FVB9/Capture4.png

Comment: In OutlookSpy, what do you see if you click Namespace, select Accounts property, click Browse? What do you see if you click IOlkAccountManager and select pclsidCategory = CLSID_OlkMail?

Comment: OutlookSpy? I'm not using this